# UIImageView Picker giving exception in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePicker to load image from library but it gives exception 
saying use popover for ipad.I tried those also but not working any idea how to fix this issue.

```
   UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Opening UIImagePicker in ipad or iphone  use Bellow code:-

**#define isiPhone  (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == 0)?TRUE:FALSE**

```
 UIImagePickerController *pckrImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pckrImage.delegate = self;
if (isiPhone) {
                if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
                {
                    pckrImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                    [self presentModalViewController:pckrImage animated:YES];
                }
                else {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:pckrImage];
                [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(450.0f, 825.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];


            }
```

---

For dismiss At selection of UIImaegPicker :-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
 if(isiPhone)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iPad you must use it like:

```
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: picker];

[popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem: item
                permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated: YES];
```

or

```
[popover presentPopoverFromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
                         inView: self.view
       permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                       animated: YES];
```